# Convert numpy array to sparse matrix to find inverse and then convert back to numpy array

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, sparse-matrix, matrix-inverse

In the following function, if I use 
`np.linalg.inv` when `Nx`, `Nt` get large the function seems to take forever. In my mind I know I should instead use sparse matrices, which are in scipy (which I've never used before), but I'm getting really stuck how to convert `M` to a sparse matrix, find its inverse, and then convert it back to a numpy array for the for loop.

If anyone could help I'd be really grateful! Thanks!

`def BTCS(phiOld, c, Nx, Nt):`

```
#Initiate phi for the for loop
phi = phiOld.copy()

#Crate the matrix M for the BTCS scheme
M = np.zeros((Nx, Nx))

for i in range(Nx):
    M[i,(i-1)%Nx] = -c/2
    M[i,i] = 1
    M[i,(i+1)%Nx] = c/2

#Take the inverse of M so as to have phi(n+1) = M^(-1) * phi(n)
M_inv = np.linalg.inv(M)

#Loop over all time steps
for it in range(Nt):
    #Loop over space (excluding end points)
    for ix in range(1,Nx-1):
        phi[ix] = M_inv.dot(phiOld)[ix]
    #Compute boundary values using periodic boundary conditions
    phi[0] = M_inv.dot(phiOld)[0]
    phi[Nx-1] = phi[0]

    #Update old time value
    phiOld = phi.copy()

return phi
```

Comment: Sounds trivial given the docs of scipy-sparse. But the more important question is: can't you get away without inverting, e.g. by solving Ax=b (matrix-inverse calculations should be the last approach given it's problems). [Probably read this](https://www.johndcook.com/blog/2010/01/19/dont-invert-that-matrix/).

Comment: This did not even cross my mind at all (problem with spending hours on coding)! So in this case, use spsolve? I got confused by the scipy-sparse documentation because there were so many forms of sparse matrix

Comment: Yes, spsolve in the sparse case. solve for the dense one. spsolve, according to the docs can actually take your dense-array as input. And if you do the conversion by hand, it will also use internally a sparse-matrix which is good for this calculation (csr or csc; not sure; so calling with lil for example won't crash, but it's not the best approach).

Comment: And given your task, when you try to build your sparse-matrix (without the dense first): use a format which is good for incremental construction (if you want to keep your loop), e.g. ```M = dok_matrix((Nx, Nx))```, which supports efficient single-element access. Then you can call spsolve with that (and it will be converted automatically). Actually it probably makes sense to convert to whatever spsole likes manually as you construct a single-time but solve much more times. **Edit:** and as M does not change, reuse the factorization! -> ```lu = linalg.splu(A)``` and ```x = lu.solve(b)```.

Comment: You can create a sparse matrix from the dense one with just: `sparse.csr_matrix(M)`.  If `M` is very large, pushing the memory limits you can create the sparse matrix directly.  In this case one of the sparse diagonal functions might be handiest.

Comment: How large would you deem "very large"?